# PostgreSQL Drop Table Invalid Argument

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I would also like to delete a table in PostgreSQL.

I can delete the table I just opened, but when I want to delete a previously opened table I get the following error:

```
DROP TABLE "ABTestCreateTable4";
```

> DROP TABLE  "ABTestCreateTable4"
>
> > ERROR:  vsnprintf failed: Invalid argument

```
DROP TABLE "ABTestCreateTable4" CASCADE;
```

> DROP TABLE "ABTestCreateTable4" CASCADE
>
> > ERROR:  vsnprintf failed: Invalid argument

I tried two options but I got the same error.

I've searched for this problem, but I can't find any solution.

I'm using Navicat Premium.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: looks strange. I cannot to repeat it on current versions of PostgreSQL. Please, try update your Postgres.

Comment: That is valid SQL. The error message looks strange though. Maybe Navicat can't cope with those dreaded quoted identifiers.

Comment: Is this error an error with Navicat?

Comment: What happens when you drop the table using the `psql` client?

Comment: I'm trying, hopefully it works.

Comment: Try to reproduce the error with `psql`. If cou cannot, it is probably not a PostgreSQL problem. If you can reproduce it, run `\errverbose` to get details and add those to the question.

Comment: I found a solution to the problem. Lines with default value are not deleted, so it gives error. For example, uuid_generate_v4 () default function id column so are not deleted. Why do these functions fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
SET lc_messages = 'C'
```

and then  `DROP TABLE table_name`

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Why did this happen? Do you have any information?

Comment: you can have a look at this link for details:
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/2510.1542487896%40sss.pgh.pa.us